# Timeout on a java cache

Tags: java, caching, nonblocking

We have a simple but very much used cache, implemented by a ConcurrentHashMap.  Now we want to refresh all values at regular times (say, every 15 minutes).

I would like code like this:

```
 private void regularCacheCleanup() {
        final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long delta = now - cacheCleanupLastTime;
        if (delta < 0 || delta > 15 * 60 * 1000) {
            cacheCleanupLastTime = now;
            clearCache();
        }
  }
```

Except it should be:

- Thread safe
- Non-blocking and extremely performant if the cache isn't going to be cleared
- No dependencies except on java.* classes (so no Google CacheBuilder)
- Rock-solid ;-)
- Can't start new threads

Right now  I think to implement a short timer in a ThreadLocal. When this expires, the real timer will be checked in a synchronized way.  That's an awfull lot of code, however, so a more simple idea would be nice.

Comment: What's the reason for not using libraries like EHCache?

Comment: I would suggest the same @benny23, using EHCache it's as simple as configuring refresh time on a XML file if you won't do it programaticaly

Comment: This will be used in a library, included in lots of other applications;, some of them in very bad shape.  The library already has lots of dependencies. History has proven that each dependency introduced makes maintenance of the applications harder, e.g. by introducing version conflicts etc..  This means  I Try to get rid of dependencies, not introduce new ones.

Comment: From what it sounds ConcurrentHashMap might not be the right choice for you. In order to allow concurrent access it provides weakened semantics (i.e. weakly consistent iterators, approximate results in size() and isEmpty()) that might not be what you would want in your implementation of a cache.

Comment: @lefty We don't need a fullblown cache implementation.  A simple dumb store for  about 10 to 1000 values does what we want.  Even a few  extra cache misses and inconsistencies every few minutes are acceptable, as long as they are temporary

Comment: If you cannot start new threads, then it will be quite difficult to make a runnable job which cleans your cache for every 15minutes. That points to my question: Why do you want to start no other threads?

Comment: @user844382 I see. Have you then considered using a scheduled thread pool executor for your cache synchronization task? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: Main problem with threads is that this runs in an application server, and there is no event available when the cache should shut down.  I've seen a thread implementation in the past in some other code, and when the applicaton gets redeployed, stopped/started,... the old thread keeps running, causing a clasloader leak and all kinds of weird bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mainstream way to tackle this issue would be by using some timer thread to refresh your cache on specified intervals. However, since you don't need to create new threads, a possible implementation that i can think of is that of a pseudo-timed cache refresh. Basically, i would insert checks in cache accessors (put and get methods) and each time clients would use this methods, i would check if the cache needs to be refreshed before performing the put or get action. This is the rough idea:

```
class YourCache {

  // holds the last time the cache has been refreshed in millis
  private volatile long lastRefreshDate;

  // indicates that cache is currently refreshing entries
  private volatile boolean cacheCurrentlyRefreshing;

  private Map cache = // Your concurrent map cache...

  public void put(Object key, Object element) {
    if (cacheNeedsRefresh()) {
      refresh();
    }
    map.put(key, element);
  }

  public Object get(Object key) {
    if (cacheNeedsRefresh()) {
      refresh();
    }
    return map.get(key);
  }

  private boolean cacheNeedsRefresh() {
    // make sure that cache is not currently being refreshed by some
    // other thread.
    if (cacheCurrentlyRefreshing) {
      return false;
    }
    return (now - lastRefreshDate) >= REFRESH_INTERVAL;
  } 

  private void refresh() {
    // make sure the cache did not start refreshing between cacheNeedsRefresh()
    // and refresh() by some other thread.
    if (cacheCurrentlyRefreshing) {
      return;
    }

    // signal to other threads that cache is currently being refreshed.
    cacheCurrentlyRefreshing = true;

    try {
      // refresh your cache contents here
    } finally {
       // set the lastRefreshDate and signal that cache has finished
       // refreshing to other threads.
       lastRefreshDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
       cahceCurrentlyRefreshing = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Personally i wouldn't consider doing it like so, but if you don't want or can't create timer threads then this could be an option for you.

Note that although this implementation avoids locks, it is still prone to duplicate refreshes due to race events. If this is ok for your requirements then it should be no problem. If however you have stricter requirements then you need to put locking in order to properly synchronise the threads and avoid race events.

Comment: This is more or less what happens, except that put is only done when the get doesn't return anything. Thus, I would reformulate the question as: Give a performant implementation of cacheNeedsRefresh.  Main issue  is that lastRefreshDate needs to be volatile or the method needs to be sycnhronized or something like that, and we are in a highly threaded environment.

Comment: This is what Guava does in some of its cache maps IIRC BTW

Comment: I have updated my code according you your comment. I don't know demanding are your requirements but generally, i don't think that using volatile variables is so much of a performance penalty (at least compared to locks). Anyway, i can't think of another way of doing this in java without using either locks or volatile variables. If performance is such an issue that your really can't spare the use of volatile reads and writes, well, i'd be looking on some other technology with a different concurrent programming model (i.e. Actors in Erlang or Scala).